# Uploading a doc file Directly in Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, file-upload

I want to save and retrieve a Word doc and PDF file with a size of 1 MB, directly in MongoDB with Node.js. How can I do this is there any article explain about it or can some one help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the standalone node js code to save the file as binary data in MongoDB. As the maximum file size is 1MB, you can save it in normal collection rather than GridFs.

This can be extended to run as web apps using "express" or "hapi" frameworks. You may need to refer the respective tutorial for that.

**Save the file as binary data in MongoDB:-**

Note: I have the sample file in "docs" directory. So, I have prefixed it with docs (i.e. "/docs/testplan.docx"). You can remove that if you don't need it.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var Binary = MongoClient.Binary;
var fs = require('fs');
var assert = require('assert');

var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';

var binaryFileData = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/docs/testplan.docx"); 

var insertDocument = function(db, callback) {
   db.collection('file_save').insertOne( {
       "fileName" : "testplan.docx",
       "fileData" : binaryFileData
   }, function(err, result) {    
        assert.equal(err, null);
        console.log("Inserted a document into the collection.");
        callback();
  });
};

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  insertDocument(db, function() {
      console.log("Closing the database connection...")
      db.close();
  });
});
```

**Read the file data and save it to disk:-**

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var Binary = MongoClient.Binary;
var fs = require('fs');
var assert = require('assert');

var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';

var findDocument = function (fileName, db, callback) {
  db.collection('file_save').findOne({"fileName" : fileName }, function (err, document) {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    console.log(document.fileName);
    fs.writeFileSync("testplan_out.docx", document.fileData.buffer);
    console.log("File has been written to disk");
    callback();
  });

};

MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  findDocument("testplan.docx", db, function () {
    db.close();
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you please let me know how to do you can see below my code

Answer (score 0):

that works perfectly alright! But I'm trying to **upload the document** from the **POSTMAN** and I'm developing my project with **MEAN stack**.

```
//document-model.js
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var documentSchema = {
   docFile: {
      type: String
   }
};
mongoose.model('FileDocument', documentSchema);

//document-route.js
var express = require('express'),
    documentRoute = express.Router(),
    document = require('../controllers/document-controller');

documentRoute.post('/upload', document.uploadDocument);
module.exports = documentRoute;


//document-controller.js
var document = {
    uploadDocument: function (req, res) {
        var fileDocument = new FileDocument({
            docFile: req.body.docFile
        });
        fileDocument.save(function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                res.status(500).send(err);
            } else {
                res.status(200).send('Document Uploaded Successfully');
            }
        });
    }
};
```

I was trying in this way but it is not uploading to mongodb the result is gives in the mongo shell.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59693872b8b83f42b42a3b9f"), "docFile" : "", "__v" : 0 }
```